# Android App - trouble setting AlertDialog view with custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-alertdialog, listadapter

I am trying to use the following code to put a ListView with a custom ListAdapter into an AlertDialog. Currently the activity will display the AlertDialog, but with no ListView displayed:

```
public class EditMindMapActivity extends Activity {

    private Button NewObjectButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_mind_map);

        // Assign external resources
        NewObjectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);       

        // Set the listener for the interact button
        NewObjectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //create text field for user input
                final EditText textField = new EditText(EditMindMapActivity.this); //the ed..this might be wrong

                /*          Create selection images ListView            */
                    //just for placeholding really
                ListView listView1 = new ListView(EditMindMapActivity.this);
                listView1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                listView1.setCacheColorHint(00000000);
                ArrayList<Drawable> images = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
                //fill up the list of images
                images.add(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.shape01 ));
                images.add(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.shape02 ));
                images.add(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.shape03 ));
                images.add(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.shape04 ));
                images.add(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.shape05 ));
                images.add(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.shape06 ));
                images.add(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.shape07 ));
                images.add(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.shape08 ));

                // add to the list here
                CustomListAdapter01 adapter = new CustomListAdapter01(images, EditMindMapActivity.this); 
                listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int position, long itemId)
                    {
                        //nothing
                        //probably set some variable
                    }
                });
                /*                      ^^^^^^^^^^^                     */


                /*          Display Select Image AlertDialog            */
                    //may want to make this an external function

                // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditMindMapActivity.this);

                // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
                builder.setMessage("where will this be?")
                .setView( listView1 )
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           //since the user hit 'ok', set imageLocation and ask the user to name the object ->

                           //this int holds the selected image location
                           final int imageLocation = R.drawable.shape05;
                           //final int imageLocation = listView1

                           /*           Display Input Text AlertDialog          */

                           //might have problem because of overwriting previous builder methods
                           builder.setMessage("Enter a name for the New Object")
                           .setView(textField)
                           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   //since the user hit 'ok', create the object specified ->

                                   //need this to reference mindMapView and access it's arrays
                                   MindMapView mindMapView = (MindMapView)findViewById(R.id.MindMapView);
                                   //get the string from the input, set it to the label of the new object
                                   mindMapView.mindMapArrayListLabels.add( textField.getText().toString() );
                                   //add the correct image.
                                   mindMapView.mindMapArrayListImgs.add(imageLocation);
                                   //move the index to the end position of the arrays
                                   mindMapView.imageIndex = (mindMapView.mindMapArrayListLabels.size() - 1);
                                   //redraw the view
                                   mindMapView.invalidate(); 
                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   //since the user hit 'cancel', don't do anything
                               }
                           })
                           .setTitle("Might not need this")
                           .show();
                           /*                   ^^^^^^^^^^^                     */
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           //since the user hit 'cancel', don't do anything
                       }
                   })
                   .setTitle("Choose an image:")
                   .show();
                /*                  ^^^^^^^^^^^                     */




            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_mind_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my CustomListAdapter01 class:

```
public class CustomListAdapter01 extends BaseAdapter {

    //contains all of the images that will be displayed
    ArrayList<Drawable> images;

    Context context;

    public CustomListAdapter01(ArrayList<Drawable> images, Context context) {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.images = images;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        Drawable image = images.get(position);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(image);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Here is the XML file 'child_layout':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
```

should be the below as the adapter needs to know the size of the list:

```
  @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        images.size();
    }
```

Comment: CAN SOMEONE GIVE ME A VOTE UP FOR THIS